# How to view recently opened media files?

Tags: filemanager

In windows we have an option to view recently opened media files as my recent documents, I was  wondering does there exists something like that in Ubuntu?

via terminal or via GUI?

Comment: Open Nautilus (files) and look at the top left of the window it says "recent", click this

Comment: @markkirby there is no recent anything saying recent in the window, only file, edit view go etc..

Comment: Added a screenshot for you

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate, as the question here seems to prefer a Nautilus-oriented answer): [Where are my “recent documents” in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67924/where-are-my-recent-documents-in-unity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all kind of activities are being recorded in Ubuntu. For me the **Unity Dash** (<kbd>Super</kbd>) always is a convenient place to find recently accessed files, applications, or media:

- [image] Default screen showing recent applications, files, and Downloads

  [image]
- [image] Music screen showing recent music files

  [image]

  The search can be further refined with filters as seen on the right side of the Dash window.
- Similarly we can search for applications only, documents only, or videos from the bottom menu.

To disable this feature, make sure it is enabled, or use different settings look for privacy settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open Nautilus (files) and look at the top left of the window it says "recent", click this

[image: open recent files]

Comment: sorry no recent option in mine