# Window-snapping fails completely with all applications; Ctrl+Super+Left / Ctrl+Super+Right do nothing

Tags: 16.04, window, snap-windows

Dragging to the top of the screen also does nothing.

- Dragging windows to the left or right does nothing
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> maximizes successfully,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> unmaximizes, and minimizes windows
- Dragging windows to the bottom of the screen
  moves them to the lower workspace
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ClickDrag windows moves that
  window

I don't recall messing with any settings, it just happened all of a sudden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view recently opened media files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517134/how-to-view-recently-opened-media-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by following this post: [Ctrl + Super + Left/Right not working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821954/ctrl-super-left-right-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

```
$ sudo apt install  compizconfig-settings-manager
$ ccsm
```

And then in the window that pops up, click "Window Management", then check the box next to "Grid" and in the alert box, click "Ignore conflicts"

Someone in the linked question said it might have something to do with Dell computers, and my computer is made by Dell.